# Why does this unhiding of elements fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

My Meteor app uses Template.dynamic to replace the previous Template with the next. I've set this up like so in the "main" html file:

```
<div class="container">
   {{> postTravelWizard}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="postTravelWizard">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getStepTemplate}}
    <button type="button" name="nextStep" id="nextStep">Next</button>
</template>
```

...and here is some pertinent JavaScript diesbzg.:

```
   Session.setDefault('stepNum', 1);

   Template.postTravelWizard.helpers({
        getStepTemplate: function () {
            var step = Session.get('stepNum');
            switch (step) {
                case 5:
                  return 'tblFundOrgAccountActivityAmount';
                  break;
                case 4:
                  return 'tblExpenseDescription';
                  break;
                case 3:
                    return 'tblPayments';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return 'tblTravelerInfo2';
                    break;
                default:
                    return 'tblTravelerInfo';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }); // Template.postTravelWizard.helpers
```

This all works pretty well -- not *extremely* well, though, because my the HTMLTable "columns" that I hide like this:

```
<template name="tblExpenseDescription">
  <button type="button" name="addDate" id="addDate">Add another Date</button>
  <br />
  <table class="maintable" name="tblExpDesc" id="tblExpDesc" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="centertextnowrap"><strong>Description of Expense</strong></td>
        <td class="centertext"><label>Date 1: </label><input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 3: </label><input type="date" id="date3" name="date3"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 4: </label><input type="date" id="date4" name="date4"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 5: </label><input type="date" id="date5" name="date5"/></td>
        <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 6: </label><input type="date" id="date6" name="date6"/></td>
        <td class="skybluebackground centertext"><label><strong>Total Expenses</strong></label></td>
        <td colspan="4" class="nobordercell centertext"><label>Comments</label></td>
    </tr>
. . .
</template>
```

...(by assigning certain HTML elements the CSS "hide" class) are not unhidden when the "Add Another Date" button is clicked. That class is:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

The first time the "Add Another Date" button is clicked, it should reveal/unhide/show the "column" for Date 2; if the user clicks it again, it should show the "column" for Date 3, etc. Here's that code:

```
   Session.setDefault('nextDate', 1);
   . . .
   Template.postTravelWizard.events({
    'click #addDate': function(event){
       var nextD8 = Session.get('nextDate');
       nextD8 = ++nextD8;
       Session.set('nextDate', nextD8);

       if (nextD8 == 2) {
          $("#date2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#airfare2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#pcm2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#reimbursemlg2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#rcei2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#ot2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#parktolls2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#confreg2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#lodging2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#mealsandI2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#foreignanddomestic2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#miscandenter2").removeClass("hide");
          $("#totals2").removeClass("hide");
       } // If/when this works, add code for the others, or figure out a less brute-forcish way to accomplish the same thing
    } // 'click #addDate': function(event){
}); // Template.postTravelWizard.events
```

There is no err msg, but removing the "hide" class on those elements does nothing. Why not?

Comment: Use chrome dev tools or firebug to inspect the element. Make sure the hide class is actually being removed. Is it? If so, are there any display:none; visibility:hidden etc. being applied from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 'hide' class is applied to the td elements, but in your Js file you are removing the class from #date2, which is an input.

Apply the ID of date2 to the td element instead and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on bluejaybr's accepted answer, here is what I did:

0) Changed this sort of HTML:

```
<td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
```

...to this:

```
<td class="centertext hide" id="tdDate2"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
```

(added a "tdBla" id to the td elements)

1) Changed the Javascript from this:

```
$("#Date2").removeClass("hide");
```

...to this:

```
$("#tdDate2").removeClass("hide");
```